# In Swift package building for Any iOS Device: Cannot find type 'EdgeInsets' in scope

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swift-package-manager

When I build this very simple Swift Package, I get this compiler error:

```
/Users/benleggiero/Desktop/Test/Sources/Test/Test.swift:4:11: error: cannot find type 'EdgeInsets' in scope
extension EdgeInsets: P {}
          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

#### Package.swift

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Test",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "Test",
            targets: ["Test"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "Test",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "TestTests",
            dependencies: ["Test"]),
    ]
)
```

#### Sources/Test/Test.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension EdgeInsets {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that you're building for an iOS device, it appears that you also have to explicitly define your platform(s) in the `Package.swift` file in order for it to not give this error:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "StackOverflowLibrary",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13),
        .macOS(.v10_15)
        ],
    //etc.
```

Note that this alone continued to not work for me until I also did a "Clean build folder", at which time it compiled correctly.

Comment: Gosh... thank you. I wish it weren't like this 